# thermoplastic polymers

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, materials

I'm looking for polymer to fit injection molding (thermoplastic):

The final injected part (small part of volume approximately $\pu{300mm3}$) should be transparent, because a stainless steel tube will be inserted to a hole inside the part and adhesive using UV will be accomplished to attach the tube to the part.

Good mechanical properties of the polymer would be a bonus. For example, polycarbonate can be used, but I'm looking for additional material.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help] if you have any questions about the site. Regarding your question, I'm not quite clear on what you are looking for. For example, you said polycarbonate can be used: what is it that is desirable about polycarbonate for your project, and what is undesirable about it that makes you look for something else? Also, you refer to "good" mechanical properties, which is pretty unclear. I think if you [edit] your question to clarify just what your needs are, you'll have  better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Lots of polymers absorb UV, so the UV-set adhesive inside the part may be the hardest issue.